# Keys ^, ~ and ¨ appear selected when writing them

Tags: macos, keyboard

Whenever I write the keys **^**, **~** and **¨**, just after pressing the key, they're written but they appear selected. It seems I had this problem for a long time, but it started to annoy me now when trying to use the keys in vim, as I can't use them correctly.

The problem repeats in every textfield, and I've done some research but I'm unable to identify what's causing it.

I'm writing on a MacBook Pro Spanish ISO keyboard with the latest MacOS (11.2.3).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It´s a feature of both the the Spanish layouts (regular & ISO in slightly different ways), allowing faster access to commonly used accents, by having two 'permanent' dead-keys. So you type the dead-key followed immediately by the letter you wish to add the accent to. As far as I'm aware, it's the only language layout that has this particular implementation.

[image]

If you hold  <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>  you can type without those acting as dead-keys.

The only ways I know to eliminate them are to swap to another language - but you would also lose your ñ & ç keys & have to access those using other dead keys instead.

This, for instance is the UK layout, with  <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd>  pressed to access the dead-keys.

[image]

Alternatively, have a look at [Ukelele](https://software.sil.org/ukelele/) [freeware], which allows you to build your own layout - that way you could keep the Spanish layout, but just deactivate those two dead-keys.

Comment: Thank you! I was totally unaware of this. Ukelele is a great option in macOS, I have finally deactivated these two dead-keys. [Karabiner](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/) is also a good option (only for macOS too)